# image rendition in aspect ratio

Tags: php

Hi can someone please help me, we have a website that we load full sized images to and resize on the fly to 150x200px or 200x150px depending on landscape or portrait. We use the resized image for the index page where it's displayed in a table and the full sized image later in the site. My problem is, when we call the image for use in the index we have an image area of 100x100px but this distorts the image to 100x100px instead of 100x75px or 75x100px
here is a section of code we use

```
 $dynamicList .= '<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6">
        <tr>
          <td width="20%" valign="top"><a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '"><img style="border:#666 1px solid;" src="inventory_images/resized_' . $id . '.jpg"  width="100" height="100" alt="' . $product_name . '" border="1" /></a></td>
          <td width="80%" valign="top">' . $product_name . '<br />
            £' . $price . '<br />
           <a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '">View Product Details</a></td>
        </tr>
      </table>';
    }
} else {
    $dynamicList = "We have no products listed in our store yet";
```

I've tried removing the height 100x width100 but this results in the images being rendered as 200x150px

my question is, how do I render images of 200x150px into a space of 100x100px and maintain aspect ratio
the home page is rushleighs.co.uk

Answer (score 1):

You just remove the height declaration in both attributes and css. That will maintain aspect ratio. However, if you want to keep the image contained to 100 x 100, you would need a container for the image and set its overflow to hidden:

```
<div class="image_small">
    <img src="inventory_images/resized_<?php echo $id; ?>.jpg">
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.image_small{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.image_small img{
    width:100px;
    border:#666 1px solid;
}
```

Please note, I wrote the html out as though it were not being echoed in PHP since it is my professional opinion that you should avoid echoing html in php whenever possible. However, your ACTUAL html might be this for that one td element:

```
<td width="20%" valign="top"><div class="image_small"><a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '"><img src="inventory_images/resized_' . $id . '.jpg" alt="' . $product_name . '" border="1" /></a></div></td>
```

Comment: no problem. if this was the answer you were looking for, don't forget to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ccs style of max-width and max-height

```
<style>
    .img   {max-height:100px;max-width:100px;}
</style>
```

I use this function in my gallery on [www.thomsonstravels.co.uk](http://www.thomsonstravels.co.uk)

```
<?php
//I set the $_SESSION[wHeight] and $_SESSION[wWidth] when the site is first loaded
//and reset it when the browser is resized to the Screen Size and height.
function resize_values($image)
    {
        $maxWidth = $_SESSION[wWidth]; 
        $maxHeight = $_SESSION[wHeight];
        $img_size=getimagesize($image);
        $origWidth=$img_size[0];// Current image width
        $origHeight=$img_size[1];// Current image height

        // Check if the current width is larger than the maxWidth
        if($origWidth > $maxWidth)
            {
                $ratio = $maxWidth / $origWidth;   // get ratio for scaling
                $newWidth=$maxWidth; // Set new width
                $newHeight=round($origHeight * $ratio);  // Scale height by ratio
            }
        else 
            {
                //else set the new height and width to the original
                $newWidth=$origWidth;
                $newHeight=$origHeight; 
             }
        // Check if current height is larger than maxHeight
        if($newHeight > $maxHeight)
            {
                $ratio = $maxHeight / $newHeight; // get ratio for scaling
                $newHeight=$maxHeight;   // Set new height
                $newWidth=round($newWidth * $ratio);  // Scale width by ratio
            }
        $retval = "$newWidth|$newHeight";
        return $retval;
    }
//and to use this:
    $file="../images/my_image.jpg";
    $d=explode("|",resize_values($file)); //Call the function file name & path
    $resizeWidth = $d[0]; //retrieve width from the array
    $resizeHeight = $d[1];//retrieve the Height from the array
    echo"
    <img 
        src=\"$file\"
        style=\"
            width:$resizeWidth"."px;
            height:$resizeHeight"."px\"
    >";
?>
```